# Multiple ItemTypes in Listview utilizing Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a project i'm working on that needs to populate a list of categories with subitems between them. Basically a restaurant menu with categories (ex: appetizers) and food items listed within that category. I'm trying to use entity framework, and I was wondering there was a possible way to have two Model types bound to one listview.

For example, here is my aspx page:

```
                <asp:ListView ID="CatList"  
            ItemType="FOTW.Models.Category"               
            runat="server"
            SelectMethod="GetCat" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">
                    <a href="/ItemList.aspx?id=<%#: Item.id %>"><%#: Item.CatDescn %>
                    </a>
                </b>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemSeparatorTemplate>  <br/>  </ItemSeparatorTemplate>     
        </asp:ListView>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
        public IQueryable<Restaurant> GetName([QueryString("id")] int? restId)
    {
        var _db = new DatabaseContext();
        IQueryable<Restaurant> query = _db.Restaurants;
        if (restId.HasValue && restId > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.id == restId);
        }
        else
        {
            query = null;
        }
        return query;
    }
```

This pulls the ID from the default page when you select a restaurant and populates a listbox with the categories.

I'm currently just redirecting to another page for the food items that also queries the ID in the URL and populates a listbox based on that, but that doesn't really make sense for a resturant menu. Any suggestions?